# How to calculate a limit of this function for checking integral convergence?

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\lim _{x\to 1^+}\frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{x^3-x^2-x+1}}$$

I want to calculate the check if the integral $$\int _2^{\infty }\frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{x^3-x^2-x+1}}$$

is converge. I want to do so with the comparison test.

Comment: Are you sure that the lower bound of the integral is $2$ and not $1$ ?

Comment: Use L'hopital's rule to find the limit.

Comment: Do you know that $\lim_{x\to \infty}(\ln x)^A/x=0$ for every $A$? So for all sufficiently large $x$ we have $0<\ln x<x^{1/4}$.

Comment: @user254665 why it can help

Comment: Do not use L'Hopital, that is, if you want to get some understanding of the situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the substitution $u=x-1$ the limit becomes
$$
\lim _{x\to 1^+}\frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{x^3-x^2-x+1}}=\lim _{u\to 0^+}\frac{\ln (1+u)}{\sqrt{u^2(u+2)}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}
$$
observing that for $u\to 0$, $\ln(1+u)\sim u$ and $\sqrt{u^2(u+2)}\sim \sqrt{2}u$.

So the integral (I suppose the correct lower limit of integration is $1$)
$$
J=\int_1^\infty \frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{x^3-x^2-x+1}}\mathrm d x=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln (1+u)}{\sqrt{u^2(u+2)}}\mathrm d u=\int_0^\infty f(u)\mathrm d u
$$
Split the integral in two
$$
\int_0^\infty f(u)\mathrm d u=\int_0^1 f(u)\mathrm d u+\int_1^\infty f(u)\mathrm d u=J_1+J_2
$$
Observing that $\ln (1+u)\le u$ for $u>0$,
$$
J_1=\int_0^1\frac{\ln (1+u)}{\sqrt{u^2(u+2)}}\mathrm d u\le\int_0^1\frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2(u+2)}}\mathrm d u=\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{u+2}}\mathrm d u\le\int_0^1\frac{1}{u^{1/2}}\mathrm d u
$$
and reminding tha $\int_0^1\frac{1}{u^{p}}\mathrm d u$ converges for $p<1$, it follow that $J_1$ converges.

For $u\to\infty$ we have
$$
f(u)\sim \frac{\ln u}{u^{3/2}}
$$
and observing that
$$
\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln u}{u^{p}}\mathrm d u=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{(1-p)^2} &\text{for }p>1\\
+\infty &\text{for }p\le 1&\end{cases}
$$
we have that $J_2$ converges because $p=\frac{3}{2}>1$.

Thus $J$ converges.

Answer (score 2):

To find the limit - substitution  x = z + 1:

$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 1^+}\frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{x^3-x^2-x+1}}=\lim_{x\to 1^+}\frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{(x-1)^2(x+1)}}=\lim_{z\to 0^+}\frac{\ln (z+1)}{z}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{z+2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$